# upload file via curl in controller codeigniter and return result to view

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, curl, model-view-controller

Hi i am new in CI and php i want to upload file to server using curl and return the result back to the view but it's not working 
**here my controller**

```
  $issue_name = $this->input->post('issue_name');
  $issue_tagline = $this->input->post('issue_tagline');
  $issue_description = $this->input->post('issue_description');
  $issue_publish_on = $this->input->post('issue_publish_on');
  $issue_file = $this->input->post('issue_file');

$data2=array(
  'issue_name' => $issue_name,
  'issue_tagline' => $issue_tagline,
  'issue_description' => $issue_description,
  'issue_file' => $issue_file,
 ); 

$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->view('issue_detail',$data2);


  echo '<pre>' .var_dump($issue_name).'</pre>';

  $target_url = 'https://platform.twixlmedia.com/admin-api/1/upload';

  $file_name_with_full_path = realpath($issue_file);
  $post3 = array(
'admin_api_key'    => 'da06751194bc18cc60xxxxxxx',
'app_key'          => 'bd7cf04226c58723cxxxxxx',
'issue_identifier' => $productid,
'issue_file'       =>'@' . realpath($issue_file),
'issue_name'       => $issue_name
  );

$ch3 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://platform.twixlmedia.com/admin-api/1/upload');
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post3);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result3 = curl_exec($ch3);
curl_close ($ch3);
echo $result3;
```

and this is my view:

```
<form class="editissueform" action="home/editissue" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="issue_name"><br>
            <label for="tagline">Tagline:</label>
            <input type="text" name="issue_tagline"><br>
            <label type"description">Description:</label>
            <input type="text" name="issue_description"><br>
            <label type"publishdate">Publish Date:</label>
            <input type="text" name="issue_publish_on"><br>

        </div>
        <h4>Upload Publication</h4>
        <div class="issuedit">

            <input type="file" name="issue_file" size="40" />
            <h4>Please Upload using pdf file format</h4>

        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
        </form>
```

i don't know what i'm missing in my code
thanks for your help

Comment: What errors do you get ? You may want to serialize `$post3`with `http_build_query()` something like: `curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post3)); `

Comment: no error. After i submit the button it redirect to same page but without the article id (localhost/ideocreative/index.php/home/detail_issue/issue_detail instead localhost/ideocreative/index.php/home/detail_issue/issue_detail/25237) and in server api i check nothing change after i fill all form and hit submit button

Comment: already tried http_build_query() but still can't upload to server